# Easymock - mocking inner class/interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mocking, easymock

I have a problem with the creation of mocks from inner interface.

I would like to mock HttpClient from javax.ws.rs.client

So i have done this in following way.

```java
mockedClient = createMock( Client.class );
webTarget = createMock(WebTarget.class);
Invocation.Builder  builder = createMock( Invocation.Builder.class ); //<-error
response = createMock( Response.class );
```

Do you have any idea how to do it by using EasyMock?
I thougth about implements this interface and mock the method which I use in implementation. Is it a good workaround?

How this interface look like:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package javax.ws.rs.client;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.ws.rs.client.AsyncInvoker;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback;
import javax.ws.rs.client.SyncInvoker;
import javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public interface Invocation {
    Invocation property(String var1, Object var2);

    Response invoke();

    <T> T invoke(Class<T> var1);

    <T> T invoke(GenericType<T> var1);

    Future<Response> submit();

    <T> Future<T> submit(Class<T> var1);

    <T> Future<T> submit(GenericType<T> var1);

    <T> Future<T> submit(InvocationCallback<T> var1);

    public interface Builder extends SyncInvoker {
        Invocation build(String var1);

        Invocation build(String var1, Entity<?> var2);

        Invocation buildGet();

        Invocation buildDelete();

        Invocation buildPost(Entity<?> var1);

        Invocation buildPut(Entity<?> var1);

        AsyncInvoker async();

        Invocation.Builder accept(String... var1);

        Invocation.Builder accept(MediaType... var1);

        Invocation.Builder acceptLanguage(Locale... var1);

        Invocation.Builder acceptLanguage(String... var1);

        Invocation.Builder acceptEncoding(String... var1);

        Invocation.Builder cookie(Cookie var1);

        Invocation.Builder cookie(String var1, String var2);

        Invocation.Builder cacheControl(CacheControl var1);

        Invocation.Builder header(String var1, Object var2);

        Invocation.Builder headers(MultivaluedMap<String, Object> var1);

        Invocation.Builder property(String var1, Object var2);
    }
}
```

Exception from console:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:258)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newInstance(Proxy.java:753)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:744)
at org.easymock.internal.JavaProxyFactory.createProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:30)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:113)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:94)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.niceMock(EasyMock.java:181)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.createNiceMock(EasyMock.java:349)
at 
at 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie.<clinit>(Cookie.java:61)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
... 41 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:114)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:207)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
... 45 more
```

Edit:

When I add mockito to project and mock this object like this:

```java
Invocation.Builder  builder = mock( Invocation.Builder.class );
```

It works !

So the question is, why this mock doesn't work in EasyMock?

Comment: Would it be easier to move the inner interface out, then mock it?

Comment: Also, please post code, not images of code.

Comment: But this interface is inside the java library, not in my implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

`Invocation.Builder` is using a class called `CacheControl`. This class has a static field calling `RuntimeDelegate.getInstance()`. So a `RuntimeDelegate` is needed. The default `RuntimeDelegate` is `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl` which is not in your classpath. Which is why you get a `ClassNotFoundException` on it.

Mockito works for a weird reason. They implement their mock using ByteBuddy. This doesn't require to load `CacheControl` for some reason.

EasyMock mocks interfaces using `Proxy.newProxyInstance`. This, it seems, does load `CacheControl`. So it fails.

However, if you then call `builder.cacheControl(new CacheControl());` with Mockito, you will get the same error.